# Conditionally create dropdownlist with same name

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a value coming in from the Model to determine whether I am in create mode or edit mode... If I'm in Edit mode, I want to set the value of a dropdownlist to the value last saved. If I am in create mode, I want to default my dropdownlist to a default value....

***.ASCX**

```
<% if(Model.isCreate == true)
   {
        Html.DropDownList("myOptionListName", 
                           new SelectList(ViewBag.MyOptions, "Id", "Name"),
                           Resources.Global.DefaultMenuItem, 
                           new { style = "width:200px" });
   }
   else
   {
        Html.DropDownList("myOptionListName", 
                           new SelectList(ViewBag.MyOptions, "Id", "Name", 
                           ViewBag.LastSavedOption), 
                           new { style = "width:200px" });
   }%>
```

If I only use one or the other without the if, the one menu works in only one scenario... I need to use "myOptionListName" as the name because I have other javascript that references this. As it stands now, the code above doesn't render any drop down.

Q: How can I get the menu to appear based on the if check but have the same name?

Comment: There is no need for your `if` block. If the value of `myOptionListName` matches the value of one of the options, then it will be selected so set the vale in the controller. And learn to use view models!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your select list created based on your mode of the form and then assign the appropriate select list to your control.

```
<% var selectList = new SelectList(ViewBag.MyOptions, "Id", "Name");

   if(!Model.isCreate)
   {
        selectList = new SelectList(ViewBag.MyOptions, "Id", "Name", 
                           ViewBag.LastSavedOption);
   }

   Html.DropDownList("myOptionListName", selectList , 
                           new { style = "width:200px" });
   %>
```